# Difference between normalizing and averaging with probability sum rule

Tags: probability-theory, set-valued-analysis

Given a joint distribution $X,Y$, I'm trying to get the probability of $X=x$ using the sum rule:
$$P(x)=\int f(x,y)dy.$$
I undestand that I need to solve for the normalizing constant $K$, to obtain a well-defined density function:
$$1=\int K f(x)dx, $$
but I've also read that we can have
(Zadeh 1968):
$$P(x)=\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$$

for any positive, measurable and unnormalized $f$. From this, I'm inferring that
$$P(x)=\int K f(x,y)dy=\mathbb{E}_Y[f(x,y)]$$
holds for some set-valued $X$, which I do not know if it is true (and how to proof it, in that case): please help.

*Zadeh, L. A.*, [**Probability measures of fuzzy events**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(68)90078-4), J. Math. Anal. Appl. 23, 421-427 (1968). [ZBL0174.49002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0174.49002).

Comment: Could you define f(x,y) in this context?

Comment: thanks for reply @herbsteinberg, I'm supposing $f$ is an unnormalized, positive and measurable function uniquely... that's a sufficient condition?

Comment: Your comment is too vague.  Could you give an example of what you mean?  What is the connection, if any, between x and y?

Comment: I am a little confused as to what the question precisely is but allow me to make some comments that may or may not relate. If $f(x,y)$ is a joint density of $(X, Y)$ then $f_X(x):=\int f(x,y)dy$ is the marginal distribution of $X$ (where the integral is over the range of $Y$). If $f$ is a sufficiently nice function, then for any point $x$, $\mathbb{E}(f(x))=f(x)$ since $f(x)$ is non-random. If $X$ is a RV, then LOTUS gives, $\mathbb{E}(g(X))=\int g(x) f_X(x) dx$ where $g$ is any bounded and (Borel) measurable function, and the integral is over the range of $X$.

Comment: Lastly $P(X\in B)=\int_B f_X(x)dx=\int_B \int f(x,y) dy dx$ for any Borel set $B$. I hope writing down some standard relationships might help sort out the problem you’re after. If not, sorry for the noise!

Comment: I'm supponsing that $X,Y$ is a joint distribution (I edited with this), however $f(\cdot)$ is not a density (e.g. $f(x)=e^{-|x-\mu|^2/2\sigma^2}$, for any $\sigma$) as it is unnormalized (so the need for the $K$). Overall, I'm trying to get a density function from the unnormalized function without providing explicitly the evidence through $K$. I'm sure how Zadeh did it for his "fuzzy events" (which I prefer to see as set-valued RVs) such that $P(X)=\int_XdP=\int_{\Omega}f_X(x)dP=\mathbb{E}[f_X(x)]$, where $x\in\Omega$.

Comment: For Zadeh, $f_X(x)$ is a membership function (a positive measurable but unnormalized function), which is not a density function. I'd like to understand this kind of characterization using the correct facts for the case of the joint distribution, probably using the sum rule and without the need for explicit normalization.

Comment: (Edit from above: **I'm not sure** how Zadeh did it)